# How to fix json code to split in a table using dplyr

Tags: r, json, dplyr

I'm trying to split this json code into an easier way to parse my data, I have tried to use `jsonlite` with `fromJSON()` but doesn't work.

#### Data

```
{
    "PROB": 0.066977381909206,
    "Y": -3.221016563928024,
    "x": 933
}
```

```
library(jsonlite)

jsonStr <- '{
    "PROB": 0.066977381909206,
    "Y": -3.221016563928024,
    "x": 933
}'

t = fromJSON(jsonStr)

> t
$PROB
[1] 0.06697738

$Y
[1] -3.221017

$x
[1] 933
```

#### expected output

```
        PROB         Y   x
1 0.06697738 -3.221017 933
```

Comment: It seems you want a data.frame rather than a list. You can just convert it with `as.data.frame(t)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a tibble (data frame) from the parsed JSON data:

```
library(jsonlite)

jsonStr <- '{
    "PROB": 0.066977381909206,
    "Y": -3.221016563928024,
    "x": 933
}'

t <- fromJSON(jsonStr)

# create an empty data frame to store the result
df <- data.frame()

# loop through each variable in the list
for (name in names(t)) {
  df[name] <- t[[name]]
}

# assign row names
rownames(df) <- "1"

df
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 3
    PROB     Y     x
   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1 0.0670 -3.22   933
```

Comment: Hi Talha, How can I automate this for n variables? My real data has ~100 variables.

Comment: you can create a loop for it, I have updated the code please see.